# Dynamic Grid Layout with Textviews on First Row and First Column

Tags: android, forms, layout, dynamic, grid

I have a problem designing a form dynamically. It is in tabular form like the one below:

```
|        |  Great |  Good | Average | Bad |
|Quality |        |   -   |         |     |
|Perform |        |       |    -    |     |
|Support |    -   |       |         |     |
```

The first row (Header row) and first column are dynamic, that is, the rows and columns can increase or decrease and will come from a web service. The other cells will act like buttons, only one button will be activated ( - ) in a row.

Does any one have any idea how to achieve this?

Here what i done using Linear layouts: This is only a Mock data, and i have not implemented any click events or to capture user inputs (i don't know how to do it) is it involves managing IDs..

ScreenShot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzbVBFzhlWapbzlFeWlJSVF5M1k/edit?usp=sharing

The object Models i used are replica of real Object model.

```
//Table Form Type Layout
private void createFormWithLinearLayouts() 
{
    //Get Feedback Answer List
    ArrayList<FeedbackAnswer> feedbackAnswerList = feedbackQuestionSection.getFeedbackAnswerList();

    //Get Feedback Question List
    ArrayList<FeedbackQuestion> feedbackQuestionList = feedbackQuestionSection.getFeedbackQuestionList();

    //For loop for Questions
    for(int i= -1; i< feedbackQuestionList.size();i++)
    {
        LinearLayout cLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        cLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        cLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        MarginLayoutParams  params = new MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        //For loop for AAnswers
        for (int j = -1; j < feedbackAnswerList.size(); j++)
        {
            TextView tv;
            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setWidth(100);
            tv.setHeight(50);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);

            if(i == -1 && j== -1)
            {
                tv.setText(" ");
            }
            else if(i == -1 && j!= -1)
            {
                tv.setText(feedbackAnswerList.get(j).getDesc());
            }
            else if(j != -1)
            {
                //Buttons or Simply Color Change for Select or DeSelect

                //Get Answer from Question
                FeedbackAnswer feedbackAnswerOfQuestion = feedbackQuestionList.get(i).getFeedbackAnswer();

                if(feedbackAnswerList.get(j).getSeqNo() == feedbackAnswerOfQuestion.getSeqNo())
                {
                    tv.setText(feedbackAnswerList.get(j).getDesc()); //The PreSelected Answer will Come from Server
                }
                else
                {
                    tv.setText(" - - -");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setWidth(80);
                tv.setHeight(50);
                tv.setLayoutParams(params);

                tv.setText(feedbackQuestionList.get(i).getDesc());
            }

            cLayout.addView(tv);
        }


        parentLayout.addView(cLayout);
    }
}
```

/*** Data Prepared in  Object Models

```
//Prepare Feedback Question Section 
public void prepareFeedbackQuestionSection()
{
    //Question Section (Whole Layout)
    feedbackQuestionSection = new FeedbackQuestionSection();


    /******** Answers will show as Header row **************/
    FeedbackAnswer feedbackAnswer1 = new FeedbackAnswer();
    feedbackAnswer1.setDesc("Great"); 
    feedbackAnswer1.setSeqNo(1);


    FeedbackAnswer feedbackAnswer2 = new FeedbackAnswer();
    feedbackAnswer2.setDesc("Good"); 
    feedbackAnswer2.setSeqNo(2);

    FeedbackAnswer feedbackAnswer3 = new FeedbackAnswer();
    feedbackAnswer3.setDesc("Average"); 
    feedbackAnswer3.setSeqNo(3);

    FeedbackAnswer feedbackAnswer4 = new FeedbackAnswer();
    feedbackAnswer4.setDesc("Bad"); 
    feedbackAnswer4.setSeqNo(4);

    //Answer List (Row Header Texts)
    ArrayList<FeedbackAnswer> feedbackAnswerList = new ArrayList<FeedbackAnswer>();
    feedbackAnswerList.add(feedbackAnswer1);
    feedbackAnswerList.add(feedbackAnswer2);
    feedbackAnswerList.add(feedbackAnswer3);
    feedbackAnswerList.add(feedbackAnswer4);

    /*** Questions will show as First Column Texts **************/
    FeedbackQuestion feedbackQuestion1  = new FeedbackQuestion();
    feedbackQuestion1.setDesc("Quality"); 
    feedbackQuestion1.setSeqNo(1);
    feedbackQuestion1.setFeedbackAnswer(feedbackAnswer3);

    FeedbackQuestion feedbackQuestion2  = new FeedbackQuestion();
    feedbackQuestion2.setDesc("Performance"); 
    feedbackQuestion2.setSeqNo(2);
    feedbackQuestion2.setFeedbackAnswer(feedbackAnswer2);

    FeedbackQuestion feedbackQuestion3  = new FeedbackQuestion();
    feedbackQuestion3.setDesc("Support"); 
    feedbackQuestion3.setSeqNo(3);
    feedbackQuestion3.setFeedbackAnswer(feedbackAnswer4);


    //Question List (First Column Texts)
    ArrayList<FeedbackQuestion> feedbackQuestionList = new ArrayList<FeedbackQuestion>();
    feedbackQuestionList.add(feedbackQuestion1);
    feedbackQuestionList.add(feedbackQuestion2);
    feedbackQuestionList.add(feedbackQuestion3);


    //Add to Question Section
    feedbackQuestionSection.setFeedbackAnswerList(feedbackAnswerList);
    feedbackQuestionSection.setFeedbackQuestionList(feedbackQuestionList);
}
```

/** Layout */

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

/** OnCreate() */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.feedback_form_dynamic);

    //Get Linear Layout
    parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    //Prepare Data
    prepareFeedbackQuestionSection();

    //Create Form
    createFormWithLinearLayouts();
```

}

Comment: Hi , well i have not write any code ,I am experimenting with Table layout and simple linear layouts programmatically, but am unable to achive this. Regarding Grid Layout i didn't know how to work with two differnt array list,  The text views in the Header row is an arraylist  and the textviews in first colunm is another arraylist.

Comment: I think Grid is not working in this scenario can you please post code what have you done using Linear or Table Layout ?

Comment: @user3675110 what you have tried just show us..so will be able to understand ur problem more nicely

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post to include more info and what i have code with linear layouts.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot and reading about grid view , i made gridview with dynamic content and also handle on item click events to capture user input.

Screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzbVBFzhlWapTG9vbWREZllNeFU/edit?usp=sharing

There are basically two array lists : Question List and Answer List , both contains 'description ' and a 'sequenceNo' (or level).

/***Adapter *****/

```
private class FeedbackAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<FeedbackAnswer> feedbackAnswerList;
    ArrayList<FeedbackQuestion> feedbackQuestionList;

    public FeedbackAdapter(FeedbackQuestionSection fSection) 
    {
        feedbackQuestionList = fSection.getFeedbackQuestionList();
        feedbackAnswerList = fSection.getFeedbackAnswerList();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {   
        return ((feedbackAnswerList.size() +1 )* ( feedbackQuestionList.size() +1 ));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) 
    {
        if(index == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if(index <= feedbackAnswerList.size())
        {
            return feedbackAnswerList.get(index - 1);
        }
        else // if(index % (feedbackAnswerList.size() + 1) == 0)
        {
            return feedbackQuestionList.get((index) / (feedbackAnswerList.size() + 1) - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(DynamicFormDemo.this);
            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent,false);
        }

        TextView textView=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        //Get Item
        QuestionPaperInterface question = (QuestionPaperInterface) getItem(position);

        if(question != null)
        {
            if(question instanceof FeedbackAnswer)
            {
                question = (FeedbackAnswer) question;
                textView.setText(((FeedbackAnswer) question).getDesc());
            }
            else if(question instanceof FeedbackQuestion)
            {
                question = (FeedbackQuestion) question;

                if(position % (feedbackAnswerList.size() + 1) == 0)
                {
                    textView.setText(((FeedbackQuestion) question).getDesc());
                }
                else
                {
                    //Tag Answer
                    textView.setTag(R.id.feedbackAnswer, feedbackAnswerList.get(position % (feedbackAnswerList.size() + 1) - 1));

                    //Tag Question
                    textView.setTag(R.id.feedbackQuestion, ((FeedbackQuestion) question));

                    FeedbackAnswer feedbackAnswer = ((FeedbackQuestion) question).getFeedbackAnswer();
                    int seq = feedbackAnswer.getSeqNo();

                    //Get Tagged Answer
                    FeedbackAnswer taggedFeedbackAnswer = (FeedbackAnswer) textView.getTag(R.id.feedbackAnswer);

                    int taggedSeqNo = taggedFeedbackAnswer.getSeqNo();

                    if(seq == taggedSeqNo)
                    {
                        textView.setText(feedbackAnswer.getDesc());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textView.setText("---");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText("---");
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

/*** On Item Click**//

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    //Get View
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;

    //Get Feedback Answer list
    ArrayList<FeedbackAnswer> feedbackAnswerList = feedbackQuestionSection.getFeedbackAnswerList();

    if(position >= feedbackAnswerList.size() + 1 && position % (feedbackAnswerList.size() + 1) != 0)
    {
        //Get Tagged Feedback Question
        FeedbackQuestion feedbackQuestion = (FeedbackQuestion) textView.getTag(R.id.feedbackQuestion);

        //Get Tagged Feedback Answer
        FeedbackAnswer feedbackAnswer = (FeedbackAnswer) textView.getTag(R.id.feedbackAnswer);

        //Set New Answer in Question
        feedbackQuestion.setFeedbackAnswer(feedbackAnswer);

        //Notify Adapter
        feedbackAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        String toastMessage = "Feedback Answer is :" + feedbackAnswer.getSeqNo() + ": "+feedbackAnswer.getDesc();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

/******* In On Create() *****/

```
    int numOfColms = feedbackQuestionSection.getFeedbackAnswerList().size() + 1; //No of Columns = No of Answers + 1 (Blank first Row First Column)

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);  
    gridView.setNumColumns(numOfColms);
```

But It didn't fit my requirement ,this grid view scrolls vertical , which i did not need, as there are more components above and below this like a whole form of feedback which scrolls vertical. So am trying another solution using tables. I posted this in hope of it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the Problem by using Tables, adding rows and columns dynamically. The table is  contained in Horizontal Layout and whole layout is in ListView. The reason for is the table and other components may repeat and change ordering dynamically.